# Running process inside a panel in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Is there any way run a jar (or any other process) file inside a panel in vb.net?

I am trying something like this:

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Threading

Public Class FGRUPOS

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> Shared Function SetParent(ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

   Private Sub FGRUPOS_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim p As Process
        p = Process.Start("java.exe", "-jar processo.jar")
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, panel1.Handle)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But it is not working.

Comment: I don't have a jar-file handy, but your code works for me if I substitute "java.exe" with a different program, such as "notepad.exe". If you run "java.exe *****.jar" from the command line, does your Java program run?

Comment: Actually, I need to put -jar just before *****.jar. The right line would be `p = Process.Start("java.exe", "-jar *****.jar")`. Changing the code will run `notepad.exe`, but not inside a panel as I want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code bellow (from [vb.net Launch application inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651815/vb-net-launch-application-inside-a-form)) does the trick:

```
Public Class FGRUPOS

    Declare Auto Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As IntPtr, ByVal hWndNewParent As IntPtr) As Integer
    Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As Integer
    Private Const WM_SYSCOMMAND As Integer = 274
    Private Const SC_MAXIMIZE As Integer = 61488

    Friend Sub Rodar_Processo()
        Dim p As System.Diagnostics.Process
        p = Process.Start("notepad.exe")
        p.WaitForInputIdle()
        SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, pnGrupo.Handle)
        SendMessage(p.MainWindowHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MAXIMIZE, 0)
        Me.BringToFront()
   End Sub
End Class
```