# How can you take a running process and put it into a panel in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, process

Before anyone shouts 'duplicate!', it isn't (afaik)

I'm trying to host a game client inside a panel in vb.net. I've read this question;

[Running process inside a panel in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452464/running-process-inside-a-panel-in-vb-net)

The above does a great job! The only problem is I can't load the program directly by process.start since there is a separate 'user login' program that calls the main game client. Is there a method by which I can grab an already running process and put it into the panel? I can gain access to the process by this method;

Dim Win As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ClientGame").First

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself! It was pretty simpel just a question of setting the process using;

Dim Win As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("ClientGame").First

and then using this to set the parent!;

SetParent(Win.MainWindowHandle, Panel1.Handle)

This can be deleted if people don't think it's useful to keep.