# Embedding a batch game in a fixed position on a vb.net program

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I'm new to vb.net and I want to keep it simple, so I'm making a batch game and I want to embed it into a Visual Basic application so that it isn't movable and then add a soundtrack so the game isn't boring, how can I do this or is it possible?

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2a550088-7a70-4f01-b4aa-f9498c6f4738/is-it-possible-to-display-a-cmd-window-inside-the-windows-form-visual-basic?forum=vbgeneral

Comment: As I am looking into your image you might want to try out `@echo off` at the beginning of your batch file. That will stop output like `C:\Users\Alex\Desktop>echo.`

Comment: @geisterfurz007 That batch file isn't mine, it's an image off the internet XD mine looks WAY better

Comment: Although there might be hacks that will allow you to "do" this, it is *not* a good idea and will create all sorts of problems. Being new to VB.NET and apparently new to Windows programming, you are ***not*** setting yourself up for success. You will inevitably encounter difficult to debug problems that would be difficult even for an experienced Windows programer. Just don't do this. If you absolutely want to do it right, you'll need to redirect I/O from the console application to a text box in your form. If you have no idea what that means, you have no business doing this. Sorry to be blunt...

Comment: @CodyGray I already know I won't be able to do this but I want to give it a shot, there's no harm in trying , right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a solution here: [vb.net Launch application inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651815/vb-net-launch-application-inside-a-form)

Is exactly what you asked for ;)

Comment: Thanks bro I'll give this a go when I get home ;)

Comment: No prob, let me know if works

Comment: It didn't work sadly but I don't think I'll worry about this until I get better at developing, for now I think I'll keep it simple ;) thanks!

Comment: Why didn't work? Tell me the problem.. for sure i can do something :D

Comment: It just displays an error, And I didnt really know how to arrange the code and it might have not been the corrsct syntax