# How to embed a batch file to a form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm making a simple project that when I  click the button then run my test.bat inside the form. I searched in stack overflow and I found this [vb.net Launch application inside a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651815/vb-net-launch-application-inside-a-form) ,but when I put the cmd it says there is no gui. please help me to fix this. Thank you.

Comment: Process.start is the key here.  Perhaps update your question with your button click event handler calling that

Comment: I want to use my batch inside my form or a panel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651815/vb-net-launch-application-inside-a-form this is I found in stackoverflow but when going to do it , It says there is no graphical interface .

Comment: Batch files don’t tend to have much of a GUI past a simple console output.  What exactly are you expecting?  Even if it was an external application capturing the GUI to display with your app is not most simple task.  Are you maybe looking to host something like an active x control in your form?

Comment: @Hursey like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13651815/vb-net-launch-application-inside-a-form I want to run a **batch** file inside the form

Comment: Well like I said, batch files don’t have much of a gui for you to capture.  Maybe what you want to do is show the console window in as per the solution on that other question then run your batch file within that

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are searching for the StandardOutput

Are you searching something like this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=APyteDZMpYw